# Does Ext.Create in Sencha Touch 2 have a complete or success callback

Tags: callback, sencha-touch

I need to create an object in Sencha Touch 2.  This takes a few seconds to complete so I want a mask to show from the start of the function call to the end of the create process..

I have the following code:

```
Ext.Viewport.setMasked({xtype:'loadmask',message:'Please wait.'});

if (me.client === undefined)
{
  alert('got here');
  me.client = Ext.create('MyApp.view.ClientPanel',{
    title: 'Clients',
    doSomething: function(){alert('created it');},
    success: function(){alert('success');},
    suceessCallback: function(){alert('suceessCallback');}
  });
}

Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
```

As the code stands, the mask only shows when I step through the code manually using the Chrome dev tools.  I assume because it shows and hides too quick to show up..

None of the alerts show after the object is created, which doesn't really surprise me, but I can't find anything in the docco about any specific callbacks..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

seems I needed to do this instead:

```
 me.client = Ext.create('MyApp.view.ClientPanel',{
     title: 'Clients', 
     doSomething: callbackFunc()
   });

 function callbackFunc(){
   Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
 }
```